# Preserving node.js built-in imports for Electron in rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, rollup

I am making a Electron app with Svelte and Typescript.
I started with [this](https://github.com/fuzzc0re/electron-svelte-typescript) template for that exact purpose, but it disables node.js built-in imports (like fs) in the browser/electron frontend for security.

I do not need this improved security in my project, so I am trying to get node.js fs to work in the Electron browser.
I already modified the Electron Backend script that creates the Browser to re-enable nodeIntegration, and this works: using require("fs") in the Electron browser console logs the fs library.

Using this in the actual typescript frontend code does not work, however. From looking at the bundled JS, it seems like rollup is assuming that the import of fs is just available as a global variable, and trying to guess its name.

When building while importing fs and path, I get the following warnings:

```
(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins
Creating a browser bundle that depends on "path". You might need to include https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
fs (guessing 'fs')
path (guessing 'path')
```

The first warning suggests a 404 GitHub link that seems to be a polyfill for some Node built-in libraries. This isn't what I want, I want the real node.js fs library. It also informs me that I'm creating a browser bundle - I have tried setting the `browser` option of `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` (used by the template) to false, but this did not help.

The second warning seems to simply inform that it's trying to guess global variable names - which it should not, it should keep the imports.

How do I allow importing Node.js modules here? The linked template project still closely resembles my current one.
Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the deciding factor was the `output.format` of the rollup.config.js.
This was set to `iife`, which produced a result without `require` or `import`.

Changing it to `cjs` solves this problem.